# How to check if an array has an element that contains a string in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

**PostgreSQL version: 9.6**

I have `email` column in `users` table. (E.g. `john@aaa.org`)

I have an array of url domains. (E.g. [`www.aaa.org`, `www.bbb.io`, `ccc.ddd.com`, `eee.com`])

Now I want to retrieve all the emails that the array has an element that has an email domain as a substring.

This is what I got which is obviously wrong.

```
select email from users where SPLIT_PART(email, '@', 2) like any (array['www.aaa.org', 'www.bbb.io', 'ccc.ddd.com'])
```

If I have records like so:

```
users
---
id| email
1 | john@aaa.org
2 | john@bbb.io
3 | john@ccc.ddd.com
4 | john@ddd.com
```

I want to retrieve the emails of user **1,2,3.**

Comment: ccc.ddd.com, is a subdomain of ddd.com (4), so it should be a valid one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method to do what you want:

```
select *
from users u
where exists (select 1
              from unnest(array['www.aaa.org', 'www.bbb.io', 'ccc.ddd.com', 'eee.com']) ar
              where split_part(u.email, '@', 2) = replace(ar, 'www.', '')
             );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c3a5bca6798489fab8258514f9a55aec) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @masa_ekohe . . . You prefer the other answer, which was provided much later?  How is it more accurate?

Comment: just realized your answer is as accurate. Just changed the label. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

we can use `unnest` to convert your array into rows. then use case to check if it contains `www`.

```
select id, email from users t1
cross join unnest(array['www.aaa.org', 'www.bbb.io', 'ccc.ddd.com']) t2
where 
    case when  position('www' in t2) > 0 then 'www.'|| split_part(email, '@', 2)
        else split_part(email, '@', 2) end  = t2
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=1SraOovD9O)